# Dual Boot Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8 preinstalled

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8

I know that this forum is full of questions like mine, i red a lot of that questions, but till today i'm not able to boot windows on my computer.
My computer is a samsung i5 with preinstalled windows 8. 
I was following the guide of this theard [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) (the one with 139 "likes") and i installed ubuntu 12.10 (now i update it to 13.10),disabling secure boot and enabling "CSM", but i never was able to boot my windows 8 again.
When i was trying to use the "Boot Repair" app i got after rebooting black screen with this error:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal mod' not found
grub rescure>
```

then i reinstalled ubuntu trough the live Dvd and ubuntu was working fine. But i would like to have also windows 8 and when i try to boot it from the ubuntu boot menu the computer reboots and goes back to the boot menu. 
So is there anyway to fix this grub problems and boot also windows 8?

Comment: Can you show us your partition tables?

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode you cannot dual boot from grub menu. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot change. But you should be able to go into UEFI menu and change boot back to UEFI mode and Boot Windows. One time boot key may let you auto switch from UEFI to CSM. Or you can update Ubuntu from BIOS boot to UEFI boot with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I don't know why but i tried to go into the bios and it gives me some error and sturts up to the linux boot menu. I don't know now how i could enAble the uefi mode.

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/t7ysztptt/Screenshot_from_2013_12_26_17_31_20.png this are my partition, i know they are a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you Windows 8 is an operating system not recommended for Windows and also Ubuntu. It is my particular opinion. Nowadays most companies sell pcs with W8: Dell, HP, Asus, and so on. I would prefer a computer without any installed system.

Comment: I know but i also need windows sometimes and i'm a noob on ubuntu, i have it only since 4 mounths